# How to enable Internet Sharing (ICS) in Windows Server 2012 R2 VPS?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vps, internet, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a VPS running in Windows Server 2012 R2. It has one ethernet connection which is a Hyper-V Network Adapter and there is no internet sharing option on it's right click properties. How do I enable internet sharing in this vps?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Internet sharing requirements are that 2 devices exist. however, you may can consider since it's a vm, adding a second one. moreover the original way would be to use the routing function. the internet sharing features are normally only on a client site

Comment: @djdomi Any online guide on how to setup this routing function? Thanks.

Comment: I used ["windows 2012 make server router"](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+2012+make+server+router&oq=windows+2012+make+server+router&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l4j33i22i29i30l4.15499j0j7&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)  on google and one of a solution is from [this site](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/de-de/000118763/configuring-windows-server-2012-r2-as-a-router?lang=en) but this site does not allow to provide learning materials as it makes the question off topic. Moreover it's a basic mcsa task

Comment: @djdomi Will try that. Thanks.